# Uncheck radio buttons using jQuery general selectors

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have the following form (it is dynamically generated and I have a few copies of it named form-0 to form-3)

```
<form id="form-0" name="0">
<b>what is bla?</b><br>
<div class="ansN" id="ans0"><input type="radio" name="answerN" value="0"> aaa </div>
<div class="ansN" id="ans1"><input type="radio" name="answerN" value="1"> bbb </div>
<div class="ansN" id="ans2"><input type="radio" name="answerN" value="2"> ccc </div>
<div class="ansN" id="ans3"><input type="radio" name="answerN" value="3"> ddd </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit your answer">
</form>
```

(ignore the divs, they are used for some other purpose)

Itry to create an uncheck function so that will work on all the radio-buttons on the page,
so I played with the console and tried to deselect them using this:

```
$('form[id^="form-"]').find("input:radio:checked").attr('checked', false);
$('form[id^="form-"]').find("input:radio:checked").removeAttr("checked");
```

So the selector did find all the checked buttons, but it didn't uncheck them, why?
when I use direct JS call: `document.forms[0].answerN[3].checked = false` it works fine,
so I can use it inside a loop but I try to avoid loops here. Is there a better way?

My goal is to have an uncheck function, so the second click on the radio button itself will uncheck it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.6, you could use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) :

```
$('form[id^="form-"]').find("input:radio:checked").prop('checked',false);

// OR (not recommended)

$('form[id^="form-"]').find("input:radio:checked").removeProp('checked');
```

**However, it is not advised to use the `removeProp` variant, according to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) :**

> Do not use this method to remove native properties such as **checked**, **disabled**, or **selected**. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

*( thanks @noah1989 for pointing this out )*

`attr()` retrieves the value that have been set in the source code, and `prop()` retrieves the current, dynamically set value of the attribute.

You can see a [jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/mRJsY/2/)

Comment: it's not `could` but `should`: `As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() only retrieves attributes.`

Comment: @Sylvain Thrd I tried to reverse your example so it will work when clicking on the radio button itself to unceheck: `$('form[id^="form-"]').find("input:radio:checked").click(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
});
` and it doesn't seem to work, do you know why?

Comment: @IlyaD because you're binding the `click()` event on `input:radio:checked` and when you do that, there are no radio button checked. You could use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), that way as soon as a radio button is checked, it will be bound to this `click` event : `$('form[id^="form-"]').find("input:radio:checked").live("click", function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
});`

Comment: By the way, I don't see why you would want to uncheck a radio button as soon as it is checked ?!

Comment: @Sylvain Thrd I don't! I updated the question.. I should be a deselect option on an already selected button. Your code looks like it will work on a button that is already checked, but it works the instance the button is checked, how do I change it?

Comment: erm.. could you please remove the "removeProp" variant from your answer? It took me quite some time to find this: "Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead."

Comment: @noah1989 I didn't remove it, I added a warning instead. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to uncheck using

```
$('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', false);
```

My initial guess is that you get a collection of radio buttons from your `find`. Thaus you should use `.each()` to loop them and set the `checked` attribute to false on each individual one.

Something like this (not testet, so might be a syntax error)

```
$('form[id^="form-"]').find("input:radio:checked").each(
  function() {
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
  }
);
```

Comment: +1 here.  If you replace .attr with .prop I found this to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" id="ra1" onclick="change('ra1')" onmousedown="getvalue('ra1')"/>
function getvalue(id){
    ischecked = document.getElementById(id).checked;
}
function change(id){
    if(ischecked == false)
        document.getElementById(id).checked=true;
    else
        document.getElementById(id).checked=false;
}
```